# about java calculation expressions

Tags: java, boolean-operations, short-circuit-evaluation

```
import java.util.\*;

class Example{    
  public static void main(String asrg\[\]){    
    boolean b = false;    
    System.out.println(10\>4 && true !=b==(10+3/2==8)==true); //Line 1    
}
```

can anyone explain this expression?

expecting the steps how to calculate these

Comment: The code you posted won't compile, so it doesn't execute or calculate anything.

Answer (score 1):

The code provided is missing a final curly brace ('}') and will not compile. There are also some backslashes ('\') strung about that will result in syntax errors. Additionally, 'args' is misspelled but it is not necessary in order for code to compile.

With the final brace added and backslashes removed, the code is:

```
import java.util.*;

class Example
{    
  public static void main(String args[])
    {    
    boolean b = false;    
    System.out.println(10>4 && true !=b==(10+3/2==8)==true); //Line 1    
    }
}
```

Running the above code will display the answer in console. However the steps can be explained below.

First, we need to simplify our boolean expression into just terms of `true` and `false`. Since we declare that `b = false`, and the fact that`10 > 4 == true` and `(10+3/2==8) == false`, the expression that is printed can be simplified to `(true && true != false == false == true)`.

The expression can then be evaluated according to [Java's operator precedence](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html), and will evaluate to `false`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code won't compile; It's missing a `}` at the end of the class.

Also, did you copy and past this from a website? Why are there `\` all over the place?

For better readability, use the Java-style array declaration: `String[] args` instead of `String args[]`.

To check a boolean value, you don't have to compare it to `true` or `false`. This includes any actual booleans, or expressions outputting a boolean, such as: `10 + 3 / 2 == 8`, which is false.

Comment: String args[] and String[] args are the same, String[] args is just easier to read for experienced developers.

Comment: @Stultuske I have never seen that in action or even thought about it also working that way. Still seems off to me, but thanks!